# close() system call takes long time to finish

Tags: c, linux, file, linux-kernel

I am testing performance using `sendfile()` to copy big files under Linux 6.4. 
My code follows the following logic and is compiled with gcc

```
 read_fd = open (argv[1], O_RDONLY);
 fstat(read_fd, &stat_buf);
 write_fd = open (argv[2], O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, stat_buf.st_mode);

 left_to_write = stat_buf.st_size;
 while (left_to_write > 0) {
      written=sendfile (write_fd, read_fd, &offset, stat_buf.st_size);
      if (written == -1)
           return -1;
      else {
         left_to_write -= written;
         bytes_done=stat_buf.st_size-left_to_write;           
         printf("%ld bytes written, %ld bytes left to write\n", written,  left_to_write);
  }
```

}

```
     close(read_fd);
     close(write_fd);  /* this takes minutes */
```

The `sendfile()` call is very fast; I can see it writing chunks of 2GB about every 5 seconds.

When the `while` loop is over, it stays at `close(output)` for minutes before finishing successfully.

Why does `close(output)` takes so long to run? Is it flushing a buffer? How can I make it faster?

Comment: Just a bit of math: "it's writting chunks of 2GB about ever 5 seconds." means 400MB/s. What medium do you use? This is too fast for a HDD and still quite advanced for consumer SSDs. How large are the files? Provide more information, i.e. a [mcve]. See [ask].

Comment: Your `open` calls don't make much sense; should they be `input = open(…);` and `output = …something that opens a stream socket…`? Also, the arguments to `sendfile()` are different from those on BSD — is this because your code is pseudo-code or because BSD and Linux diverge?  (BSD interface: `int sendfile(int fd, int s, off_t offset, off_t *len, struct sf_hdtr *hdtr, int flags);` — I note in particular that the input file descriptor (`fd`) comes before the output stream socket (`s`) in BSD.)

Comment: Answering myself: Linux's [`sendfile()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/sendfile) is radically different from the BSD (Mac OS X) version.  Linux uses a different header (`<sys/sendfile.h>` rather than `<sys/uio.h>` on Mac OS X) and the declaration is `ssize_t sendfile(int out_fd, int in_fd, off_t * offset, size_t count);`.  So, my previous comment is not material unless you're looking to port your code to other systems — if you are, beware!

Comment: And compounding the problems still further, FreeBSD [`sendfile()`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sendfile&sektion=2) is different from Mac OS X [`sendfile()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/sendfile.2.html).  Such fun!  (It's an exercise for the reader to find out which, if any, BSD variant matches the Mac OS X definition.  Mainly, this is a "programmer beware" notice — `sendfile()` differs across systems.)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Maybe that's because `sendfile` is not part of any standard :-)

Comment: @Olaf: 100% agreed — and it is likely that `sendfile()` will not to be standardized given that there are divergent implementations for the prior art.

Comment: I want to add this behavior happens when I copy from local disk to an NFS  share.  If I copy from local disk to local disk, close() doesn't run long. however my code is slower() than cp command.

Answer (score 1):

It's due to writeback.  `close(output)` must report any write errors that have not yet been reported; for example, it must ensure that all the blocks required for the data have been allocated, or else report `ENOSPC`.

The data are not necessarily written to disk when `close()` returns; if you want this, you'll need to call `fsync()` (and endure a longer wait).

See also the NOTES section of the manual page.